# How to double buffer rectangles

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, keylistener, thread-sleep

It always works with images but rectangles and ovals never buffer right. I have a basic game loop in my gamepanel class that draws the player repeatedly. It doesn't remove the rectangle, just leaves a trace. I want to use a rectangle instead of an image for learning purposes. I tried using repaint in the game loop, but it flickered like crazy and still didn't work. I looked at another tutorial on this in this website but they used opengl witch is foreign to me and I don't want to take the time to figure it out.

JFrame:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setTitle("OMG I MADE A GAME");
        f.setResizable(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setContentPane(new Panel());
        f.pack();

        f.setVisible(true);
       }
   }
```

JPanel Class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import com.game.entity.Player;

public class Panel extends JPanel implements Runnable, KeyListener{ 

private static final long serialVersionUID = -5122190028751177848L;
    // dimensions
    public static final int WIDTH = 320;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 240;
    public static final int SCALE = 2;      
    // game thread
    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running;        
    // image
    private BufferedImage image;
    private Graphics2D g;

    private Player p;

    public Panel() {
        super();
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));
        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocus();
    }
    // DRAWS PANEL TO FRAME
    public void addNotify() {
        super.addNotify();
        if(thread == null) {
            thread = new Thread(this);
            addKeyListener(this);
            thread.start();
        }
    }

    private void init() {           
        image = new BufferedImage(
                    WIDTH, HEIGHT,
                    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB                  );
        g = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
        p = new Player(100, 100);           
        running = true;
    }

    public void run() {         
        init();
        // game loop
        while(running) {                
            update();
            draw();
            drawToScreen();  
            System.out.println("ELAPSED :" + System.nanoTime()/ 1000000 + " Seconds");              
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }           
        }           
    }

    private void update() {
        p.update();
    }
    private void draw(){
        // NAME (remember it loops) 
        String name = "2014 Jay H.";
        g.setFont(new Font("Name", 0, 12)); 
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.drawString(name, 0, 10);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect( 0, 10, 65, 5);          
        //TITLE                       looks sexy :D
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.setFont(new Font("Title", 0, WIDTH/ 10));
        g.drawString("JAY'S GAME", WIDTH/ 5, 100);
        //DRAW PLAYER
        p.draw(g);

        }
    // SCREEN IMAGE (dont have to use. Just use this^)
    private void drawToScreen() {  
        Graphics g2 = getGraphics();
        g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0,
                WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE,null);
        g2.dispose(); 
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent key) {}

    // PUBLIC KEYRELEASES
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent key) {
        int KeyCode = key.getKeyCode();             
        //EXIT SYSTEM
        if(KeyCode == KeyEvent.VK_Q) {System.exit(0);
            }           //UP
        if(KeyCode == KeyEvent.VK_W){p.setDY(-2);}      
    }       

    // PUBLIC KEYRELEASES
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent key) {
        int KeyCode = key.getKeyCode();             
        //UP
        if(KeyCode == KeyEvent.VK_W) {p.setDY(0);}
    }      
}
```

Player Class:

```
   import java.awt.Color;
   import java.awt.Graphics2D;
   import java.awt.Image;      
   import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

    //FOR NOW THE PLAYER IS A RECTANGLE
   public class Player {

    // PLAYER CORDINATES AND VELOCITY
    int x,y,dx,dy;      

    public Player(int x, int y) {           
        //NEEDED TO USE THE X AND Y
        this.x =x;
        this.y = y;
    } 

    public void update() {
        x += dx;
        y += dy;            
    }

    // DRAW TO PANEL CLASS
    public void draw(Graphics2D g) {
        //BODY
        g.setColor(Color.PINK);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20);
        //EYES
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(x+3, y+2, 5, 10);
        g.fillRect(x+ 12, y+2, 5, 10);
        //EYERIS
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(x+3, y+2, 2, 10);
        g.fillRect(x+15, y+2, 2, 10);
        //NOSE
        g.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
        g.fillRect(x+5, y+13, 10, 5);
        //NOSTRILLS
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(x+6, y+15, 2, 2);
        g.fillRect(x+12, y+15, 2, 2);           
    }

    //GET METHODS FOR CORDINATES AND VELOCITY  (Unused for now... i think)
    public int getX() {return x;}
    public int getY() {return y;}
    public int getDX() {return dx;}
    public int getDY() {return dy;}         
    //SET METHODS TO CHANGE
    public void setX(int x) {this.x = x;}
    public void setY(int y) {this.y = y;}
    public void setDX(int dx) {this.dx = dx;}
    public void setDY(int dy) {this.dy = dy;}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to "reset" the background of the buffer before you paint to it.

Remember, painting is accumilitive, that is, what ever you painted previously, will remain.  You will need to rebuild each frame from scratch each time you paint to it

Flickering will occur for two reasons...

1. You are using AWT based components, which aren't double buffered
2. You are overriding `paint` of a top level container like `JFrame`, which isn't double buffered.

You should either use a [`BufferStrategy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/bufferstrategy.html) or override the `paintComponent` method of a Swing based component, like `JPanel` which are double buffered by default